# Dual Boot Ubuntu 11.04 / Vista 32 with a RAID 0

Tags: 11.04, raid, windows-vista, grub2

I tried to install Ubuntu 11.04 several time using all the informations I could gather on the web. But I still fail to install it, and as my Vista partition contains very important informations I prefer to ask to people with some experience instead of doing a big mistake.

Here are my configuration:

---

**Physical hard-drives:**

- (HD1) Hard-Drive1 ~300 Go (RAID 0 part 1)
- (HD2) Hard-Drive2 ~300 Go (RAID 0 part 2)
- (HD3) Hard-Drive3 ~640 Go (Data's)

**- RAID 0 (HD1 + HD2) partitions:**

- Vista install (C:\ ~285)
- Development (D:\ ~225)
- The new empty partition for Ubuntu (40 Go)

**- HD3 partitions:**

- My personal data's (~560 Go)
- The second empty partition for Ubuntu (40 Go) because I was unable to install it the raid 0 drive.

---

**The problem**

When I install Ubuntu all seems ok until the following error:

> Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed.
>
> This is a fatal error.

At that time, it offers me 3 options; select another destination, continue without Grub or Cancel the installation. When I try to select another destination (the one that seems to correspond to the Ubuntu partition according to gParted) is does nothing, and if I try to continue without Grub (I could install it later) a box with the following message appears:

> We're sorry; the installer crashed...

I tried to install it on the RAID0 40Go partition, and later onto the HD3 40Go partition but both of them return the Grub error, and in the both cases I can't finalize the Ubuntu installation even without Grub.

---

**Some informations**

- I use a USB key to boot and install Ubuntu (and it boots without problem).
- The live session of Ubuntu start without any problem on the same computer.
- I was able to install and run the same ISO on virtual box on the same computer.
- The error occurs at almost 80-85% of the installation.

And finally, here are the informations returned by the Boot Info Script after cleaning the both 40Go partitions.

```
              Boot Info Script 0.60    from 17 May 2011


    ============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

     => Syslinux MBR (3.61-4.03) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
     => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdd.
     => HP/Gateway is installed in the MBR of /dev/mapper/nvidia_dffbicaa.

    sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

        File system:       vfat
        Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.03 2010-10-22 ........>..sr>..........:...0...~.....~...f...M.f.f....f..0~....>E}.u......
        Boot sector info:   Syslinux looks at sector 32144 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                   second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the  directory. 
                   The integrity check of the ADV area failed. No errors 
                   found in the Boot Parameter Block.
        Operating System:  
        Boot files:        /syslinux/syslinux.cfg /ldlinux.sys

    sdd1: __________________________________________________________________________

        File system:       ntfs
        Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7
        Boot sector info:   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
        Operating System:  
        Boot files:        

    sdd2: __________________________________________________________________________

        File system:       Extended Partition
        Boot sector type:  -
        Boot sector info:  

    nvidia_dffbicaa1: ______________________________________________________________

        File system:       ntfs
        Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7
        Boot sector info:   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
        Operating System:  Windows Vista
        Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

    nvidia_dffbicaa2: ______________________________________________________________

        File system:       ntfs
        Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7
        Boot sector info:   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
        Operating System:  
        Boot files:        /BOOTMGR /Boot/bcd

    nvidia_dffbicaa3: ______________________________________________________________

        File system:       ntfs
        Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7
        Boot sector info:   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
        Operating System:  
        Boot files:        

    ============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

    Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

    Disk /dev/sdb: 4224 MB, 4224712704 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 513 cylinders, total 8251392 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

    Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

    /dev/sdb1    *             63     8,251,391     8,251,329   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


    Drive: sdd _____________________________________________________________________

    Disk /dev/sdd: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

    Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

    /dev/sdd1               2,048 1,168,340,983 1,168,338,936   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
    /dev/sdd2       1,168,340,990 1,250,263,039    81,922,050   5 Extended
    Empty Partition.


    Drive: nvidia_dffbicaa _____________________________________________________________________

    Disk /dev/mapper/nvidia_dffbicaa: 600.1 GB, 600138055680 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 72962 cylinders, total 1172144640 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

    Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

    /dev/mapper/nvidia_dffbicaa1   *             63   598,870,014   598,869,952   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
    /dev/mapper/nvidia_dffbicaa2      1,151,907,840 1,172,137,983    20,230,144  12 Compaq diagnostics
    /dev/mapper/nvidia_dffbicaa3        598,870,016 1,069,987,823   471,117,808   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


    "blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

    Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

    /dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
    /dev/mapper/nvidia_dffbicaa1 F010DAB010DA7D52           ntfs       
    /dev/mapper/nvidia_dffbicaa2 CA6E68D76E68BE37           ntfs       Respawn Recovery
    /dev/mapper/nvidia_dffbicaa3 34FCD7C1FCD77B94           ntfs       
    /dev/sda                                                nvidia_raid_member 
    /dev/sdb1        0810-0946                              vfat       PENDRIVE
    /dev/sdc                                                nvidia_raid_member 
    /dev/sdd1        AA76186576183493                       ntfs       

    ========================= "ls -R /dev/mapper/" output: =========================

    /dev/mapper:
    control
    nvidia_dffbicaa
    nvidia_dffbicaa1
    nvidia_dffbicaa2
    nvidia_dffbicaa3

    ================================ Mount points: =================================

    Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

    /dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
    /dev/sdb1        /cdrom                   vfat       (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)


    ========================= sdb1/syslinux/syslinux.cfg: ==========================

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # D-I config version 2.0
    include menu.cfg
    default vesamenu.c32
    prompt 0
    timeout 50

    # If you would like to use the new menu and be presented with the option to install or run from USB at startup, remove # from the following line. This line was commented out (by request of many) to allow the old menu to be presented and to enable booting straight into the Live Environment! 
    # ui gfxboot bootlogo
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ================= sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

               GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

                ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1
                ?? = ??             syslinux/gfxboot.c32                           1
                ?? = ??             syslinux/syslinux.cfg                          1
                ?? = ??             syslinux/vesamenu.c32                          1

    ============== sdb1: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux: ===============

     syslinux/gfxboot.c32               :  COM32R module (v4.xx)
     syslinux/vesamenu.c32              :  COM32R module (v4.xx)

    =============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

    ./boot_info_script.sh: line 1579: [: 2.73495e+09: integer expression expected
```

---

Can any one, give me a hint or explain me why it doesn't work ?

---

Edit:

I removed the second hard drive for the moment, and then I did tried the install using the Ubuntu 11.04 **Alternate** ISO. The only choice available from the menu is *Advanced Options* / *Rescue Broken System*. Neither *Run Ubuntu from this USB* (probably normal) nor *Install Ubuntu on a Hard Disk* (is this normal ??) are available.

So I tried *Rescue Broken System*, and everything seems ok until the "Detect disks" step.
It is asked the **device to use as root file system** and the choices are:

- /dev/dm-1
- /dev/dm-2
- /dev/dm-3
- /dev/dm-4
- /dev/dm-5
- /dev/sdc1
- Assemble RAID array
- Do not use a root file system

I tried with dm-4 and I was able to install GRUB and to finish the installation.
Unfortunately, after rebooting, I went to Vista without any menu to book on Ubuntu.

Since that when I retry the *Rescue Broken System*, and when I select dm-4 as root file system, it offers me to Reinstall GRUB boot loader (which produce an error) and to execute shells, but I'm unable to continue to next step (*Partition disks*)

Does anything seems strange in this ?

---

Edit 2:

I finally managed to make GRUB work by reinstalling it on the /dev/mapper/nvidia_dffbicaa (known with the command # sudo dmraid -s).

When I boot on Vista it does work without any problem (pfuuu) but when I try to book the Ubuntu ou the Recovery Ubuntu, it fails.

Should I try to reinstall using the normal Ubuntu ISO (non Alternate) over this working Grub ?

---

Edit 3:

Ok the problem is solved. Here is how a achieved to do it.

1 - Cleaning of the 40Go partition
2 - Boot on Ubuntu *Alternate* Recovery Mode, and use of the main menu (ESC) to create the partitions (swap and ext4) and assemble the raid, then setup Grub using the RAID name (/dev/mapper/theRaidName) instead of /dev/sda.
3 - Boot on Ubuntu Normal, then proceeding to install normally until the Grub error...
4 - Reboot and all is there.

Comment: Valkea is there a way we could talk?
I've got a similar problem... http://askubuntu.com/questions/73033/need-help-to-install-ubuntu-on-win7-alienware-m17xr3-installing-not-working I didn't quite understood how u fix it but I think your fix might fix mine...
can u read my doubt and help me out?
thkz!!! :D

Comment: Sorry I'm leaving to Nepal tomorrow so I won't have time to help that much... but what is important is that I used a different version of the Ubuntu CD to achieve the installation... I used the **alternate** cd installation, which support more specific stuffs like fakeRAID, RAID etc...

Comment: Go to http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ and grab the Alternate installation. "The alternate install CD allows you to perform certain specialist installations of Ubuntu. It provides for the following situations: LVM and/or RAID partitioning; ..." etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you need to use the Alternate CD if you are going to install Ubuntu into a RAID condition.  The installer is text based, but has more capabilities than the one found on the live CD image, or USB key image.

Please read the documentation here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto

bertmanphx

Comment: That seems to be an interesting solution to try. I will read this document and give it a try if it does fit my problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, that was the first step to find the solution, so I accept this answer. thank you again.