# Problem with grub to dual-boot in raid system

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, raid

I've got two HDs in a raid system and Windows 7 installed in a partition. When I try to install Ubuntu in the other partition, the installer says the bootloader can't be installed. I've mounted Windows partition and installed Grub on it, but I'm not able to configure it's menu. When I start the computer, it gets to the standard Grub terminal (doesn't show the options to boot). As I installed Grub in the Windows partition, I have unsuccessfully tried to use C:/boot/grub/menu.lst and C:/boot/grub/grub.conf.

In a few words, I can install both Windows and Ubuntu in the raid system and install grub, but I can't configure grub to boot them (grub menu).

Maybe the answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45038/dual-boot-ubuntu-11-04-vista-32-with-a-raid-0), but I can't figure it out.

Please, help me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: I was able to resolve this by selecting the "Rescue a broken system" option on the Ubuntu Aternate's boot menu. I followed all the steps until it asked for the root file system. I chose the one Ubuntu was installed, and then I chose to open a shell. Then, I installed Grub in the MBR. Everything is pretty now!